# How to find the language of a CFG from Production rules

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm having problems in finding language of the CFG from given production rules. For example if the production rules are

\begin{align}
&S \to AS \mid \epsilon \\
&A \to aa \mid ab \mid ba \mid bb 
\end{align}

How can I find the language it describes?

Comment: Could you share something you've tried, or perhaps some examples of strings in the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom "$X \to YX \mid \epsilon$" (or "$X \to XY \mid \epsilon$") means that $X$ generates $Y^*$ (assuming there are no other productions for $X$). This means that your grammar generates $A^*$. You know what $A$ generates. Putting everything together, you should be able to find a very concise description of the language generated by your grammar.